# Comparing 2 numeric columns for similarity pairwise

Tags: python, statistical-test

There are two numeric columns in the table, how can I compare the values for similarity pairwise using statistical methods in python.

I just know that they are not normally distributed, and I don't have an idea, how to check their pairwise similarity.